Why does the cosmological constant problem not cancel automatically?
The energy density of a free scalar field is:
$$\rho_\text{bosonic} = \int^\xi_0{\frac{d^3k}{16\pi^3}\hbar\sqrt{c^2k^2 + \frac{m^2c^4}{\hbar^2}}}$$
Now, in the case of a Dirac field:
$$\rho_\text{fermionic} = -\int^\zeta_0{\frac{d^3p}{16\pi^3\hbar^3}\sqrt{c^2p^2 + m^2c^4}}$$
If we sum both together (and consider both $m$ negligible):
$$\rho_\text{bosonic} + \rho_\text{fermionic} \sim \frac{c\hbar}{16\pi^2}\left(\xi^4 - \frac{\zeta^4}{\hbar^4}\right)$$
Which, for two diverging cut-offs $\xi \rightarrow \infty$ and $\zeta \rightarrow \infty$ we may have:
$$\rho_\text{bosonic} + \rho_\text{fermionic} \sim \frac{\Lambda c^4}{8\pi G} = \rho_\text{vacuum}$$
Is this a solution to the cosmological constant problem? Is there something wrong, like there could be an asymmetry of bosonic and fermionic fields or something?

What do you understand the "cosmological constant problem" is?

The wikipedia characterization is misleading, this is not a  problem in cosmology - the constant is known from observations to be small and perhaps positive. The problem of too large vacuum energy is caused by certain interpretation of the formalism of quantum field theory, but cosmology does not require that interpretation to be correct. So it is not a problem in cosmology, it seems to be a problem for some QFT theorists. It's like claiming UV catastrophe was a problem of physics of thermal radiation - it was not, it was a problem of the RJ classical model of radiation and energy accounting.

First, let's recap the cosmological constant problem.
Here's the usual, simple version: if you just had the boson, say, then the issue would be that the integral has a power law divergence if you use cutoff regularization. If we assume the cutoff is around the Planck scale, then the quantum vacuum energy contribution to the cosmological constant is much bigger than what is observed. So the cutoff dependence has to be canceled to avoid the cosmological constant problem.
Now if you dive into renormalization theory, this isn't really fully convincing, because the whole point of renormalization is that nothing physical depends on the cutoff. A more sophisticated version of the argument is that we assume there are particles with masses around the Planck scale, and generically if we "integrate out" those particles to create a low energy effective theory that is valid well below the Planck scale (ie, for the kinds of experiments we can actually do), then those heavy particles will create large, finite corrections to the effective cosmological constant we observe.
However, the scale of the observed cosmological constant is so small in particle physics terms. So we can actually run the above argument even for, say, the electron. In other words, the effective theory that describes the accelerated expansion of the Universe applies at an energy scale below the mass of the electron. So we can integrate out the electron, and find there are corrections to the vacuum energy $\sim m_e^4$ (associated with the electron mass, not Planck scale) which are much bigger than the vacuum energy we observe.
With that, let's talk about your proposal.
What you are reaching toward, is a statement that with supersymmetry -- if there is a symmetry relating the bosonic and fermionic degrees of freedom -- then the cutoff dependence of corrections to the cosmological constant do in fact cancel. This would solve the problem described above, since if you integrate out all the fermionic and bosonic degrees of freedom with masses above some cutoff scale, the supersymmetry would guarantee their contributions to the effective cosmological constant all canceled.
However, the world is not supersymmetric. And, while supersymmetry might exist at very high energies, it definitely does not exist at the scale of electrons. So supersymmetry is not a solution to the cosmological constant problem. (Some might argue it could at least make it better, if it reduced the correction to the vacuum energy from "Planck mass" scales to "Higgs mass" scales, if supersymmetry were to be found with near-future colliders).
In practical terms, the issue is that if you use the actual particles we have in particle physics, you won't find a cancellation between the bosons and fermions, like you have in your toy example.

Could you please quote or link some serious detailed and logically coherent argument/calculation showing how QFT predicts immense vacuum energy? Much of non-relativistic QFT that is checked by experiments (spontaneous emission, Lamb shift, Casimir forces) does not require zero point energy to be a real energy, and works well without it. Vacuum energy is a formal property of a field harmonic oscillator, and can be easily eliminated by different definition of energy (based on Hamiltonian in normal ordering, not the canonical one).

Really good answer!

@JánLalinský I would disagree with people who call "naturalness" problems like the cosmological constant or hierarchy problem a rigorous prediction. I would call it an expectation based on deriving low energy effective field theories from UV complete theories, that heavy particles will give large corrections to relevant operators if there is no symmetry preventing them from doing so. (...)

(...)  It could be that the effective field theory logic underlying naturalness problems is wrong. However, effective field theory does provide a physical interpretation of renormalization, and no one has a compelling alternative story beyond either "anthropics" or "that's just the way it is." So, the field is kind of stuck. A discussion that I like are in these notes by Burgess: https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4133
